# Embedded Hazelcast in Kubernetes does not form a cluster

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I was trying to use embedded mode Hazelcast in Kubernetes env. However, I found that the nodes did not form a cluster. I am confused that if the code I use is incorrect or there is something I ignored.
My application.yaml goes as follows:

```
mode: embedded
embedded:
  port: 16701
  kubernetes:
    enabled: true
    serviceDns: hazelcast-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

And the method I configured my embedded Hazelcast goes as follows:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getKubernetesConfig().setEnabled(true)
  .setProperty("service-dns", "hazelcast-service.default.svc.cluster.local");
```

I followed the README in this [Hazelcast Discovery Plugin for Kubernetes](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/)

Also, even though I follow the above GitHub instruction, I found that the piece of code I posted does not come from *hazelcast-kubernetes* dependencies, *hazelcast-all* instead.

Comment: 1) You should use either the programmatic configuration or the declarative configuration
 2) Did you add the plugin dependency on the classpath?
 3) Can you post the logs?

Comment: Actually, "hazelcast-service.default.svc.cluster.local" was injected through Springboot. Therefore, I wrote the value in application.yaml. `2021-03-23 18:25:09.133  INFO 26 [main] --- c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService     [StandardLoggerFactory.java:49] [10.233.65.41]:16701 [embedded] [4.1]

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
        Member [10.233.65.41]:16701 - c4a0aa70-17aa-4095-af64-f4d4af04512f this
]`.   I set the replicas=3. However, only one member. I think the three nodes splitted and did not form a cluster

Comment: You posted the log but did answer neither 1) nor 2).

Comment: I added the dependency on my class path. I am confused what kind of logs you mentioned. I use java-based configuration to initial Hazelcast. The values were injected from application.yaml. Thus, I posted both yaml and code

Comment: You can check the related Hazelcast Guide: https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-embedded/

Comment: Thanks. I add another property, i.e service-port. And then it works

Answer (score 1):

Without enabling diagnostics or even having the console output it's hard to say with 100% certainty; however, it appears you are attempting to use port: 16701 and hazelcast is still using 5701 since the resource file is after the hazelcast jar file in your classpath. Please ensure your yaml file is the first entry in the classpath and try again. The hazelcast jar file contains a default configuration file so it's important that it is not first in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to the logs, I found that the embedded service's Hazelcast port is not specified. I guess due to this, the member cannot find each other.